# Automatically binding multiple interfaces to one impl in Guice

Tags: java, guice

I have a design like the own shown below, with one interface extending multiple parent interfaces, and one implementation of that interface.

[image: Class diagram]

In my client classes I want to depend only on one or more of the parent interfaces, rather than the `ZooKeeperClient`. I feel like this is a better design as it reduces the surface area of my client class's dependencies, and it also makes it easier to mock things in tests.

e.g.

```
@Inject
public Foo(ServiceUpdater su) {
    // ...
}
```

However, in order to achieve this I need to manually add bindings from each interface to the implementation class:

```
bind(ServiceCreator.class).to(ZooKeeperClientImpl.class)
bind(ServiceDeleter.class).to(ZooKeeperClientImpl.class)
bind(ServiceUpdater.class).to(ZooKeeperClientImpl.class)
// ...
bind(ZooKeeperClient.class).to(ZooKeeperClientImpl.class)
```

Is there any way I can avoid this repetition and tell Guice to bind the whole hierarchy at once? Something like...

```
bind(ZooKeeperClient.class/* and its parents*/).to(ZooKeeperClient.class)
```

If not, is there something wrong with my design here? Am I doing something un-Guicy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such way in Guice, you may use a utility like [ClassUtils.getAllInterfaces()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.html#getAllInterfaces%28java.lang.Class%29) to iterate over all interfaces and bind them.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and the link.

Answer (score 1):

In [Silk](http://www.silkdi.com) you can do [`autobind`](http://www.silkdi.com/userguide/binds.html#auto) on the implementation type.

```
autobind(ZooKeeperClientImpl.class).toConstructor();
```

This will bind the class to all its interfaces and super classes (except `Object`). These binds are *weaker* than *explicit* binds - so binding one of `ZooKeeperClientImpl` super types to something else

```
bind(ServiceUpdater.class).to(AnotherImplementation.class);
```

would *dominate* the *autobind* done so that you don't get conflicts because of *ambiguous* binds.

Silk is very much like Guice so if you don't have to much Guice code it is easy and fast to change.

Comment: Never heard of Silk before. Will give it a try for my next project. Thanks!